# css menu with thick underline

Tags: css, menu, subitem

I'm trying to mimic the look of this menu but fix the errors.: http://349ghgg83g.weebly.com/

When you hover over "Home" then move to "portfolio" a underline appears under "portfolio" As it should. But when you go from "contact" to "portfolio" the underline doesn't appear. Also in my version I can't go from from "portfoilo" to it's sub-items very well because the sub-items will disappear. 
I don't have the code for the page because it's Weebly, but I've tried to reproduce it here:
http://jsfiddle.net/247t1aW3b/DnRfR/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="home.css" type="text/css"/>
</head>

<body id="body1">  
<div id="nav-wrap">
    <ul id="nav">   
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul><!-- END nav -->   
</div><!-- END nav-wrap -->    

<div id="content">
<p>Home content</p>
<p>Home content</p>
<p>Home content</p>
<p>Home content</p>
<p>Home content</p>
<p>Home content</p>
<p>Home content</p>
<p>Home content</p>
<p>Home content</p>
<p>Home content</p>
<p>Home content</p>
<p>Home content</p>
<p>Home content</p>
<p>Home content</p>
<p>Home content</p>
<p>Home content</p>
<p>Home content</p>
<p>Home content</p>
<p>Home content</p>
<p>Home content</p>
<p>Home content</p>
<p>Home content</p>
<p>Home content</p>
<p>Home content</p>
<p>Home content</p>
<p>Home content</p>
<p>Home content</p>
<p>Home content</p>
<p>Home content</p>
<p>Home content</p>
<p>Home content</p>
<p>Home content</p>
<p>Home content</p>
<p>Home content</p>
<p>Home content</p>
<p>Home content</p>
<p>Home content</p>
<p>Home content</p>
<p>Home content</p>
<p>Home content</p>
<p>Home content</p>
<p>Home content</p>
<p>Home content</p>
<p>Home content</p>
<p>Home content</p>
<p>Home content</p>
<p>Home content</p>
<p>Home content</p>
</div>

<div id="footer"></div>   

</body>
</html>
```

The CSS:

```
/* a[href="http://www.google.com"] {color: green;}   */

html {
   min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  width: 100%;  /*960px;*/
  /* padding:100px 0; */
  margin:0 auto;
  font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;
}

#body1 {
 background-image:url('speckle.jpg');
 background-repeat:repeat;
}

#content {
     width: 90%;
     margin-left: 3%;
     margin-top: 90px;
     margin-bottom: 45px;
}

#nav-wrap {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 55px;
  /*background: #336699;*/
}    

#nav {
  /*border:1px solid #ccc;*/
  /*border-width:1px 0;*/
  list-style:none;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  padding:0;
  width: 400px;
  text-align:center;
}

#nav li {
  position:relative;
  display:inline;
}

#nav a {
  display:inline-block;
  /*padding:10px;*/
  padding: 8px;   /* 8 pixel padding all the way around the anchors */
}

#nav ul {
  position:absolute;
  /*top:100%; Uncommenting this makes the dropdowns work in IE7 but looks a little worse in all   other   browsers. Your call. */
  left:-9999px; /* hide the unordered list by moving it off-screen. */
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  text-align:left;
}

#nav ul li {
  display:block;
}

#nav li:hover ul {
  left:0px; /* show the sub-items in the unordered list by moving it back under the list */
}

#nav li:hover a {  /* highlight the sub-items when you move over them */
  /*border-bottom:1px solid grey;*/
  /*text-decoration:underline;*/
  /*border-bottom-width: thick;*/
  /*background:#f1f1f1;*/
}

#nav li:hover ul a {
  text-decoration:none;
  background:#EEE;
  border-bottom:1px solid #aaa;  
}

#nav li:hover ul a:hover {
  /*text-decoration:underline;*/
  border-bottom:1px solid #aaa;
  /*background:#f1f1f1;*/
  background: #BEBEBE;
}

#nav ul a {
  white-space:nowrap;
  display:block;
  /*border-bottom:3px solid red;*/
}

a {
  /*color:#c00;*/
  color: black;
  text-decoration:none;
  /*font-weight:bold;*/
  font-weight: normal;
}

a:hover {
  /*text-decoration:underline;*/
  border-bottom: 3px solid #002EB8;
 /*background:#f1f1f1;*/
}

#footer {
  visibility: none;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Firebug or Chrome Javascript console to inspect the page. The problem is in the dropdown when you hover over portfolio. The drop down menu when is not hovered is:

```
<div id="wsite-menus">
    <div style="position: absolute; left: 203.35px; display: none; top: 166px;" class="wsite-menu-wrap">
    </div>
</div>
```

When you hover from 'Home' to 'Portfolio' the 'top' css property is set to '168px', but when you hover from 'Contact to 'Portfolio', the 'top' property stays at 166px. So the drop down menu is actually covering up the underline, the underline is not the problem here.

Comment: Ok thank you. Any idea how I can fix the disappearing portfolio sub-items?